# How do I troubleshoot which function is responsible of infinite recursion when building a package?

Tags: r

I am building a small package and everything seemed to run fine, but after cleaning my session and reloading the package with `devtools::load_all(".")` I got the following error message:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
In addition: Warning messages:
1: character(0) 
2: character(0) 
3: character(0) 
4: character(0) 
5: character(0) 
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

How do I find out which function is responsible for infinite looping?

Comment: If the information in your question is literally the only thing I have to go on, I'd simply start removing things from the package until the problem goes away. But usually there'd be a clue in the actual code (which I can't see, hence my suggestion).

Comment: @joran Ok, I assumed there was a way to locate the file in the `/R` folder that contains the problematic function. The thing is I wrote the code a while ago, everything was running fine, thus I am not sure where to start from. Probably yours is the only solution at this point.

Comment: Wouldn't you see something with `traceback()`?